# install moodle using Mariadb

Tags: mariadb

befor installing moodle on ubuntu 16.04 server i have installed MariaDB and create a privilage like this :

```
# mysql -u root -p
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE moodle;
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON moodle.* TO 'Admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
MariaDB [(none)]> \q
```

after that i can with commande line access to moodle database with user: "Admin" and password:"root".

but in the install.php page of moodle if i give the user and password i got this error :

[image: Permission denied]

what is the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

It is an old post but, for someone who hits this page:

From the error it looks like the DB type selected in the screen prior to this was "MySQLi" instead of "MariaDb".

Answer (score 0):

A bug in Moodle means it cannot detect the latest version of MariaDB database server used on all Ecenica Web Hosting packages and Managed Cloud Servers.

You can do the following:

1. Edit your Moodle config.php
2. Change $CFG->dbtype from mysqli to
   mariadb
3. Save and Restart the installation of Moodle